# JQuery: Building a dictionary with values as an array from Json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Some json data:

```
[
{
"country": "US",
"id": 1,
"name": "Brad",
},
{
"country": "US",
"id": 2,
"name": "Mark",
},
{
"country": "CAN",
"id": 3,
"name": "Steve",
},
]
```

What I'd like to do is create a dictionary from this, {country: [name id]}:

```
$.getJSON('result.json', function(result) {
    var dict = {}
    $.each(result, function(key, value){
        //build dict
    });
});

//{ 'US': ['Brad' 1, 'Mark' 2], 'CAN': ['Steve' 3]
```

What's the best way of going about this with jquery? Dictionaries constantly confound me for some reason.

Comment: what is `'Brad' 1`? Do you mean `['Brad', 1]`? `{ name: 'Brad', id: 1 }`? `'Brad 1'`?

Comment: If that's really what you want...that's awkward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$.getJSON('result.json', function(result) {
  var dict = {}
  $.each(result, function(key, value){
      //build dict
      var exists = dict[value.country];
      if(!exists){
        dict[value.country] = [];
      }
       exists.push([value.name, value.id]);
       //if it was my code i would do this ... 
       //exists.push(value);
  });  
 });
```

Personally, I don't like converting them to an array, I would keep them as values, which make them easier to manipulate.

Answer (score 1):

```
var dict = {}
$.each(result, function(i, item){
  if(!dict[item.country]) dict[item.country] = [];
  dict[item.country].push([item.name, item.id]);
});
```

You can see this in action on this [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/peterolson/AKTUS/1/).

For the data you provided, this is the result it gives:

```
{"US":[["Brad",1],["Mark",2]],"CAN":[["Steve",3]]}
```